# Merge of 2 arrays using array based list c++

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I have an assignment to merge 2 arrays,by using + operator in the class.i want to copy second list at the end of the first list.but the problem is that by code get crashed when it comes to merge the lists(a3=a1+a2).

In main i had create the 3 objects,first 2 objects will be filled by the user of string type,and then there will be merge of the above 2 list by using the operator overloading,but it get crashed when coming to it.

Sorry for my English
Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class ABlist
{
private:

    int max_size;
    int actual_size;
    T *list_array;

public:

    ABlist(int size)
    {
        max_size = size;
        list_array = new T[max_size];
        actual_size = 0;
    }

    ~ABlist()
    {
        delete[]list_array;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (actual_size == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool isFull()
    {
        if (actual_size == max_size)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int getlength()
    {
        return actual_size;
    }


    T getitem(int index)
    {
        return list_array[index];
    }


    void insertitem(T value)
    {
        if (!isFull())
        {
            if (search(value) == -1)
            {

                list_array[actual_size] = value;
                actual_size++;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << " item already present in the list" << endl;
            }

        }

        else
        {
            cout << " List is Full" << endl;
        }
    }

    int  search(T value1)
    {
        int flag = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < actual_size; i++)
        {
            if (list_array[i] == value1)
            {
                return i+1;
                break;
            }
        }

        return -1;

    }

    void removeitem(int index1)
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            if (index1 > 0 && index <= actual_size)
            {
                for (int i = index1; i < actual_size; i++)
                {
                    list_array[i] = list_array[i + 1];
                }
                actual_size--;
                cout << " Item Successfull removed from the list" << Endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << " Index is not in the range" << endl;
            }


        }

        else
        {
            cout << " list is empty " << Endl;
        }

    }

    int findandremoveitem(T value1)
    {
        int save;

        if (!isEmpty)
        {
            //save = search(value1);

            if (save != -1)
            {
                for (int i = save; i < actual_size; i++)
                {
                    list_array[i] = list_array[i + 1];
                }

                actual_size--;
                return save;
            }

            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    void displayList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actual_size; i++)
        {
            cout << " " << list_array[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    void clearlist()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
        {
            list_array[i] = -1;
        }

        cout << " List is cleared" << endl;
    }

    void Resizelist()
    {
        max_size = 2 * size;
        int *ptr1, *ptr2;

        ptr1 = new int[max_size];


        for (int i = 0; i < actual; i++)
        {
            ptr1[i] = list_array[i];
        }

        ptr2 = list_array;
        delete[]list_array;
        list_array = ptr1;

    }

     ABlist operator + (ABlist a1)
    {
        ABlist temp(100);
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a1.actual_size; i++)
        {
            if (i > a1.actual_size)
            {
                temp.list_array[i] = list_array[k];
                k++;
                temp.actual_size++;
            }

            else
            {
                temp.list_array[i] = a1.list_array[i];
                temp.actual_size++;
            }

        }

        return temp;

    }


};

void main(void)
{
    int size = 100;

    ABlist<string> a1(size);
    ABlist<string> a2(size);
    ABlist<string>a3(size);

    string name;
    string name1;
    int pos;

    cout << " FILL out the first array" << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> name;
        a1.insertitem(name);
    }

    cout << " Fill out the second array" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> name1;
        a2.insertitem(name1);
    }


    cout << " Array 1" << endl;
    a1.displayList();

    cout << " Array 2" << endl;
    a2.displayList();

    cout << " After merge" << endl;
    a3 = a1 + a2;

    a3.displayList();

}
```

Comment: That's not really a [mcve], as there's a lot of code that is irrelevant for your problem.

Comment: You create lists with size 100. And in `operator+` the temp object also has a capacity of 100. This might work in your main example of two elements each, but with larger sizes this is a sure way of crashing.

Comment: And *how* are you supposed to "merge" the two arrays? Appending one to the other? Alternate between the arrays? In some other order?

Comment: Hi Sharjeel, your code has quite a few typos. Could you please share the exact code you've compiled and used?

Comment: Kirjain,it is the same code which i compiled,actually this code include different class function which are part of my assignments which are working perfectly but only operator overloading is causing problem which is getting crashed again and again,i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

In `ABlist operator + (ABlist a1)` you pass `a1` by value, meaning a temporary copy is created. This will copy any pointers, but not the values they point to. So at the end of the function this temporary copy is destroyed, `~ABlist` gets called and `list_array` is deleted . Now the original object has a dangling pointer, which causes a crash sooner or later.

The solution is to pass by const reference<sup>1</sup>:

```
ABlist operator + (const ABlist &a1) { ... }
```

The second problem that might causes a crash is, that your temporary buffer only has a capacity of 100 for some reason. So what will happen if you merge two vectors with 100 elements each? It should be pretty easy to figure out the required size.

And the third is a logic error in the for-loop where you copy the array. The loop-condition is `i < a1.actual_size` thus, the if-condition `i > a1.actual_size` will never be true in this loop.

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but a simple solution would be iterate over all items of the current object (`this`) and use `insertItem` on each item, then iterate do the same for all items of `a1`

---

<sup>1</sup> and maybe write a copy constructor

Comment: Good catch! The same applies for returning values. So writing the copy constructor is a must.